# Webview into Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, webview, android-coordinatorlayout

Does anyone have any idea how could I use a WebView into a CoordinatorLayout?
I already have a project that uses a WebView to load a URL and I'm using Relative Layout, I tried to change it to Coordinator Layout but I'm getting tons of errors about missing classes.
Could anyone help, please?

Comment: Try syncing your gradle files once.(File->Sync Project with Gradle Files)

Comment: Can you please show Your XML code. Also the error log

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.Main3Activity">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

or inside the coordinator layout add a

```
<include layout="@layout/content" />
```

the content will have the relative layout you already created

Comment: when i replace the relative layout with the coordinator one i my app stops

Answer (score 0):

Have Rendering Problem? Simply Change Support libraries version to `alpha1`

its should look as ex.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'    
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not issue in placing `WebView` inside `CoordinatorLayout`.
If you have error in missing some classes, try to :

1. Clean & Build or Rebuild
2. Invalidate Cache & Restart